# Custom drawing in the middle of the line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, technical-drawing, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

I am making a diagram on TikZ. It requires to have a custom drawing in the middle of the connecting lines, that also must be annotated late. In the middle of the line I need to have a circle from one side and a semicircle embracing the circle from another side (from [UML Component diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/software-licensing-component-diagram-example.html?context=cmp-examples)).
Sorry for no MWE, I just have no idea where to start.

Comment: any news? you receive two answers. are no one fulfill your expectations that you can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\tikzset{
SC/.style = {% Square - Circle
    {Square[open, fill=white, length=3mm]}-{Circle[open,length=2.4mm]},
     shorten > = -1.2mm, shorten < = -1.5mm
            },
AC/.style = {% Arc -- Square
    {Arc Barb[reversed,arc=180,length=2mm]}-{Square[open,fill=white,length=3mm]},
     shorten > = -1.5mm, 
            },
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=12mm, outer sep=0pt}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=22mm and 11mm]
  \node (a) [block] {A};
  \node (b) [block,above=of a] {B};
  \draw[SC] (a) -- ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$);
  \draw[AC] ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$) node[right=2mm] {some text} -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

\tikzset{
SC/.style = {% Square - Circle
    {Square[open, fill=white, length=3mm]}-{Circle[open,length=2.4mm]},
     shorten > = -1.2mm, shorten < = -1.5mm
            },
AC/.style = {% Arc -- Square
    {Arc Barb[reversed,arc=180,length=2mm]}-{Square[open,fill=white,length=3mm]},
     shorten > = -1.5mm, 
            },
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum size=12mm, outer sep=0pt}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=22mm and 11mm]
  \node (a) [block] {A};
  \node (b) [block,above=of a] {B};
  \draw[SC] (a) -- ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$);
  \draw[AC] ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$) node[right=2mm] {some text} -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

connections between two nodes is composed from two lines:

- the first line, SC (as Square - Circle) is intended for the first part of connection between nodes. it begin with white square of size 3 and with black circle on the end. line lenght i accordingly prolonged that can be simply determined start and end coordinate.
- the second line, AC (as Arc -- Square) is intended for draw next part of connection. it begin with arc (on top of circle) and end with square
- in mwe are used separately that is evident how is connection consist. on this way it cab be easy adapted to horizontal connection.
- in real use for shorter image code is possible to define shortcut(s) with `\newcommand`(s), for example as [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) did in his answer.

**addendum:**
from question is not very clear if you also interested for design of nodes in your diagram. till now i understood that not, hence simple node used in above mwe. however, answer of [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) hinted me, that might i been wrong. he also suggest one of possible solution, but for completeness of this answer let me add my similar solution of nodes design and possible connection between two nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}  % <--- needed for draw missing line in 
                              % rectangle split node by use of
                              % "append after command={\pgfextra{...}}" 
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\tikzset{
SC/.style = {% Square - Circle
    {Square[open, fill=white, length=3mm]}-{Circle[open,length=2.4mm]},
     shorten > = -1.2mm, shorten < = -1.5mm
            },
AC/.style = {% Arc -- Square
    {Arc Barb[reversed,arc=180,length=2mm]}-{Square[open,fill=white,length=3mm]},
     shorten > = -1.5mm,
            },
picnode/.style={draw,inner sep=0pt, minimum height=1.5pt}, % <--- emblem style
emblem/.pic = {% <--- emblem on top right corner of node
    \node (aux) [picnode,minimum size=3mm] {};
    \node[picnode,minimum width=4pt,above=0.5pt] at (aux.west) {};
    \node[picnode,minimum width=4pt,below=0.5pt] at (aux.west) {};
              },
block/.style = {%
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=5,
    rectangle split draw splits=false,
    rectangle split empty part height=7mm,
    draw,
    fill=#1,  % <--- for selection node fill
    text width=44mm,
    align=flush center,
    label={[below left]north east: \tikz{\pic {emblem};} },
        append after command={\pgfextra{%
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \draw(\tikzlastnode.three split west) -- (\tikzlastnode.three split  east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}}}
            },
block/.default = white
        }
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % added for "\guillemotleft" and "\guillemotright"

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=12mm and 6mm]
  \node (a) [block] {%
        \vspace{3mm} % <--- additional vertical space above \nodepart{one}
        \nodepart{two} \guillemotleft component\guillemotright
        \nodepart{three} \textbf{Lincense Servece Net}
        \nodepart{four} artifacts
        \nodepart[align=left]{five} licence\_service.dll
                    };
  \node (b) [block=yellow!30,below right=of a] {%
        \vspace{3mm} % <--- additional vertical space above \nodepart{one}
        \nodepart{two} \guillemotleft provided component\guillemotright
        \nodepart{three} \textbf{HASP Java Native Interface }
        \nodepart{four} artifacts
        \nodepart[align=left]{five} HASP Java.dll\\
                                    HASP Java\_x64.dll\\
                                    HASP Java\_ia64.dll
                                        };
  \coordinate[right=of a] (connect);
  \draw[SC] (a) -- (connect);
  \draw[AC] (connect) node[above=2mm,align=center] {some\\ text} -| (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot, thank you. i like to add some explanation, but my english already hibernate. it is time that i go to sleep too :-). i will edit answer during saturday. by

Answer (score 1):

Building on Zarko's nice arrows, here is a proposal to do the boxes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning,shapes.multipart,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\tikzset{
SC/.style = {% Square - Circle
    {Square[open, fill=white, length=3mm]}-{Circle[open,length=2.4mm]},
     shorten > = -1.2mm, shorten < = -1.5mm
            },
AC/.style = {% Arc -- Square
    {Arc Barb[reversed,arc=180,length=2mm]}-{Square[open,fill=white,length=3mm]},
     shorten > = -1.5mm, 
            },
block/.style={
        draw,
        text width=5cm,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=5,
         rectangle split draw splits=false,
        align=center,
        append after command={\pgfextra{\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \draw ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-1mm,-1mm)$) rectangle ++(-4mm,-4mm);
        \draw[fill=white] ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-4.25mm,-1.3mm)$) rectangle ++
        (-1.5mm,-1.2mm);
        \draw[fill=white] ($(\tikzlastnode.north east)+(-4.25mm,-3.4mm)$) rectangle ++
        (-1.5mm,-1.2mm);
        \draw(\tikzlastnode.three split west) -- (\tikzlastnode.three split  east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        }
        }
}
\newcommand{\Connect}[4][]{
  \draw[SC] (#3) -- ($(#2.north)!0.5!(#3.south)$);
  \draw[AC] ($(#3.north)!0.5!(#2.south)$) node[right=2mm] {#4} -- (#2);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=22mm and 11mm,font=\sffamily]
  \node (l3) [block,fill=yellow!20] {\nodepart{two}\guillemotleft 
  provided components\guillemotright
  \nodepart{three} \textbf{HASP .Net runtime}
  \nodepart{four} artifacts
  \nodepart[align=left]{five} hasp\_net\_windows.dll
  };
  \node (l2) [block,above=of l3] {\nodepart{two}\guillemotleft component\guillemotright
  \nodepart{three} \textbf{License Services Net}
  \nodepart{four} artifacts
  \nodepart[align=left]{five} license\_service.dll
  };
  \node (l1) [block,above=of l2] {\nodepart{two}\guillemotleft application\guillemotright
  \nodepart{three} \textbf{License Status}
  \nodepart{four} artifacts
  \nodepart[align=left]{five} license\_status.exe};
  \Connect{l1}{l2}{LicenseService}
  \Connect{l2}{l3}{\guillemotleft API\guillemotright HASPA .Net}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :-) :-) ... reading op question i didn't recognize, that (s)he has problems with boxes too (otherwise i hadn't provide only simple boxes for illustration how my connections work, meanwhile i learn how to draw lines over multipart nodes with fill ;-) ). now is to late for me. anyway, i do not have much free time today :-).

Comment: @Zarko I agree that it is not in the question, but didn't you tell me that it is not straightforward to add a single horizontal line line in `rectangle splits` nodes? And I also looked up how to have some parts left-aligned.